# SharePoint 2010: Bad / slow browsing experience of a specific page in IE7

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, internet-explorer-7

We have a SharePoint 2010 site that works perfectly in firefox and ie8. In ie7 most of the pages work fine but there is one page which is pretty long and has a lot of controls like radio buttons, checkboxlist, textboxes e.t.c. It is basically an application form with a lot of questions. However in IE7 the page loads up but then when you scroll or hover over links, buttons, click on dropdown options the experience is very slow and delay. For example if you hover over a link it takes a second or two before the pointer changes into a hand.

Comment: Have you verified the behavior of this on multiple computers?  Or are you only testing it with one computer with IE7?

Comment: Yes, I have verified this from multiple location and its an issue using ie7. It only happens on this 1 page that has a lot of content.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly sounds like an issue specific to IE7 and it's rendering engine.  I would submit a bug with Microsoft as there's likely nothing StackOverflow will be able to do for you.

Comment: What I am experiencing is very similar to what this guy is expereincing in this link: http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--development-programming/ie7-slow-down-with-a-doctype-added-to-the-master-page--no-issues-on-firefox-55119.shtml